# Add custom User role for woocommerce to Only Edit ORDERS

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming, add-action

I wrote this code to create a custom user called "payment manager", this user should only edit/ view woo-commerce orders, Im have looked everywhere and didn't found any answer, see code:

```
function sitelab_simple_role() {
        add_role(
            'payment-manager',
            'Payment Manager',
            array(
                'read'         => true,
                'edit_posts'   => true,
                'upload_files' => false,
                ‘manage_woocommerce’    => false,
                'manage_woocommerce_orders' => true,
                'edit_shop_order' => true,
                'edit_shop_order_terms' => true,
                'edit_shop_orders' => true,
                'manage_shop_order_terms' => true,
                'publish_shop_orders' => true,
                'read_private_shop_orders' => true,
                'read_shop_order' => true,
            ),
        );
    }
    
add_action( 'init', 'sitelab_simple_role' );
```

For some-reason it doesn't allow to edit order with error message "you are not authorized for this action"

What could it be?

Thanks for the helpers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a few capabilities.

```
array(
        'read'         => true,
        'edit_posts'   => true,
        'upload_files' => false,
        'manage_woocommerce'    => false,
        'manage_woocommerce_orders' => true,
        'edit_shop_order' => true,
        'edit_shop_order_terms' => true,
        'edit_shop_orders' => true,
        'manage_shop_order_terms' => true,
        'publish_shop_orders' => true,
        'read_private_shop_orders' => true,
        'read_shop_order' => true,
        'assign_shop_order_terms' => true,
        'delete_others_shop_orders' => true,
        'delete_private_shop_orders' => true,
        'delete_published_shop_orders' => true,
        'delete_shop_order' => true,
        'delete_shop_order_terms' => true,
        'delete_shop_orders' => true,
        'edit_others_shop_orders' => true,
        'edit_private_shop_orders' => true,
        'edit_published_shop_orders' => true,
    ),
```